# JQuery Autocomplete strange focus behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to show data into one JQuery Autocomplete Dropdown. The information is retrieved from one dynamic ASPX:

```
$("#<%= this.txt.ClientID %>").autocomplete('<%=this.ResolveUrl("~/Page.aspx") %>')
```

Obviously I don't want make more GETs than necessary, so I have a bit of control with a Java Timer (on every keypress):

```
if (timerActive) {
    stopTimer();
}

timer = setTimeout('obtainItems()', 800);
timerActive = true;
```

And the obtain items does:

```
$("#<%= this.txt.ClientID %>").autocomplete('<%=this.ResolveUrl("~/Page.aspx") %>')
stopTimer();
```

This thing works in general, but I've seen some special behaviour with arrows and AvPag. When the records of the dropdown are displayed, if I press AvPag the component selects the correct record, but after two seconds comes back to the previous one.

My first theory was that the .autocomplete was resetting the focus, but I have noticed that this is not correct. I thought that it was a bug ([BUG LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609362/jquery-autocomplete-plugin-not-focusing-the-next-clicked-field)) but it doesn't work too.

Please, if somebody can help... thanks a lot!

Comment: you DO know that there is an option on the autocomplete to delay the get based on key strokes? ,delay: 900

Answer (score 0):

Does it work as desired without the timer?

I'm guessing your onkeypress event is fired, user selects what they want, then the timer event fires which resets the items.

add a variable

```
var selected = false;
```

and attach a **selected event** to your autocomplete and set **selected = true**

have your **obtainItem** look like this:

```
function obtainItems()
{
    if (!selected)
    {
        $("#<%= this.txt.ClientID %>").autocomplete('<%=this.ResolveUrl("~/Page.aspx") %>')
        stopTimer();
    }
}
```