# Stop jQuery autocomplete from focussing the input field after chosen from the dropdown

Tags: jquery, input, autocomplete, focus

I'm using the jQuery autocomplete plugin from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/
When a user selects a result from the dropdown, the input field gets focused. How can I stop the plugin from doing that?
I made it work using the tip from this post: [jQuery autocomplete plugin not focusing the next clicked field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609362/jquery-autocomplete-plugin-not-focusing-the-next-clicked-field)
But this only works when the user uses the mouse to select the results. Then the input field doesn't get focussed. But when the user uses the ENTER-key or the TAB-key, the input still get's focus.

Anyone knows how I can change this so that when a user has selected a value from the dropdown, the input field ddoen't get focussed?

Thank you very much in advance!

Regards, Kim

Comment: Would you be able to post a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), demo page for the problem you're having? Then we can see what's going on and make relevant suggestions.

Comment: This sounds very much like something you would want to happen. What would you like to happen when the user uses the enter or tab key?

Comment: you know that autocomplete is a part of jQueryUI now

Comment: **Note (2010-06-23):** This plugin is deprecated and not developed anymore. Its [successor is part of jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), and [this migration guide](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide) explains how to get from this plugin to the new one. This page will remain as it is for reference, but won’t be updated anymore.

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of this line in the plugin's `selectCurrent()` function:

```
$input.trigger("result", [selected.data, selected.value]);
```

...a "result" event is triggered on the autocomplete input whenever an option is selected, by mouse or by keyboard.

You can bind to that same event and put the focus on the next control in the form (which I assume is what you want, rather than just removing focus from the current one?):

```
$("input").bind("result", function () {

   // Get all controls on the form
   var controls = $(this).closest("form").find("input, textarea, select, button");

   // Find the index of the next control
   var nextIndex = controls.index(this) + 1;

   // Check if this is already the last control, so wrap around to the first one
   if (nextIndex >= controls.length) nextIndex = 0;

   // Put focus on the "next" control
   controls.eq(nextIndex).focus();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [jQuery UI's autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default)? Half of the problem is solved – when you press Tab to close the autocomplete, the input field loses focus. When pressing Enter, it's still focused, but this can be fixed easily:

```
$('#myInput').keyup(function() {
  // when Enter is pressed
  if (event.which === 13) {
    $(this).blur();
  }
});
```

#### Edit

jQuery [normalizes](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) the `event` object, so passing it as an argument is unneccessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#to" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $( "#to" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $('#to').blur();
        return false ;
    }
});
```